# Using predict() with an interaction term between categorical variable and square root transform variable

Tags: r, regression, transformation, categorical-data, interaction

I'm trying to predict the value of a response variable using predict(). My regression includes a single interaction term between one categorical variable and one transformed variable (square root transform). I've used the mtcars data set below to make sure the example is reproducable, and I've annotated it so you know what my thinking was.

```
attach(mtcars)
#take square root of weight
sqrt_wt = sqrt(wt)
#create new data frame from desired variables
df=data.frame(sqrt_wt,mpg,cyl)
#eliminate NAs caused by square root transformation
df1=df[complete.cases(df),]
#fit a regression with an interaction term (square root of weight vs.   number of cylinders as a factor)
fit1=lm(mpg~as.factor(cyl)*sqrt_wt,data=df1)
#create data frame of desired inputs for sqrt_wt
new.cars <- data.frame(sqrt_wt=c(1.7, 2.4))
#try to predict
predict(fit1,new.cars)
```

But then I get this error.

```
#Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = object$xlevels) : 
#variable lengths differ (found for 'sqrt_wt')
#In addition: Warning message:#  'newdata' had 2 rows but variables found have 32 rows
```

Any ideas? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your new dataframe doesn't have the `cyl` column. Try adding that.

Comment: @ahly Ok, that seems to have solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are making your prediction, you need all the inputs you used in the model or it can't make a prediction. Since you have an interaction, the prediction will change for each combination of `cyl` and `sqrt_wt`. In your code, it looks like both values you are specifying are `sqrt_wt`and you are missing the companion `cyl`.

```
View(new.cars)
```

Just include a `cyl` in your testset. You can add as many observations as you want in your test set. Consider all combinations of `sqrt_wt` and `cyl` that you are interested in.

```
new.car <- data.frame(sqrt_wt = 1.7, cyl = 6)
predict(fit1,new.car)
```